# Split up the "not an answer" flag reason

Tags: feature-request, flags, not-an-answer

I think it would make sense to split up the flag "This is not an answer" into three flag choices:

- This should be a comment
- This should be an edit
- This should be a new question

If we had that, it would make it easier (and therefore more efficient) for mods to figure out what to do with answers flagged thusly.

Comment: You mean like the comment options if we recommend deletion from the VLQ review queue?

Comment: @MrLister you're completely right sorry I have misread your request! my bad

Comment: You'd at least need a fourth option for cases where the "answer" has nothing to do with the question and simply needs to be deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers)

Comment: @MrLister that topic includes also 'should be a comment' concerns with 'not an answer' flag and it's still unresolved. Not an exact duplicate, but if the team solves that linked issue correctly, this **should** also deal with this problem.

Comment: Related: [Do not recommend the “not an answer” flag for conversion to a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214587/do-not-recommend-the-not-an-answer-flag-for-conversion-to-a-comment)

Comment: don't see any reason for further splitting: that'll only complicate the task of the reviewers without much benefit. The outcome is the same in about 99% of posts, they are deleted. If they deserved to be changed into a comment, you could use a custom flag, IMO. If they need editing, go ahead and do/suggest it.

Comment: Add a fourth: this is total gibberish.

Comment: @SQB No, that's not what the NAA flag is for. For gibberish, you use VLQ!